# ValueError when using yerr in a bar plot and pivot_table with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to get error bars (using `yerr`) in the same plot as a `bar` plot with `pivot_table` in pandas.

I have this code so far:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

txt = u'''Category    COLUMN1         COLUMN2     COLUMN3    
A          0.5               3          Cat1   
B          0.3               5          Cat1 
C          0.7               4          Cat1
A          0.4               3          Cat2
B          0.8               5          Cat2
C          0.3               4          Cat2
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(txt), sep="\s+")

order = ['Cat2', 'Cat1']
suborder = list("BAC")

df2 = pd.pivot_table(df,index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN2').loc[order]
df2 = df2[suborder]
df2.plot(kind='bar', yerr=pd.pivot_table(df, index='COLUMN3',columns='Category',values='COLUMN1').values)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.3, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

However this error is displayed:

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 2961, in extract_err
    raise ValueError("err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 "

ValueError: err must be [ scalar | N, Nx1 or 2xN array-like ]
```

And the plot output looks as follows:

[image: without error bars]

Plotting without error bars using  `df2.plot(kind='bar')` yields this output:

[image: simple plot]

Any ideas on what the problem (that prevents the error bars from displaying) might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reindex your yerr dataframe, to match your source dataframe, df2.

```
df2.plot(kind='bar', 
         yerr=pd.pivot_table(df,
                             index='COLUMN3',
                             columns='Category',values='COLUMN1')
                .reindex(df2.index)
                .reindex(df2.columns, axis=1))
```

Output:

[image]